# Getting Model attribute from included Module method of same name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to create a concern that can be included by different models for common mapping functionality. This module will have a method that returns a calculated value, unless the including Model has its attribute of same name already set.

For example:

```
module Mappable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    has_one :map, as: :mappable, dependent: :destroy
  end

  def centroid
    Point('123.45 321.21')  #whatever
  end

  def longitude
    super || centroid.x
  end

  def latitude
    super || centroid.y
  end
end
```

So 'super' in the method would be the Model's 'longitude' or 'latitude' attribute. If it's not set, get it from the *centroid*.

**UPDATE:**

My code actually works as written. I was not testing the concern correctly.

Comment: What is the problem with the module you have already?

Comment: NoMethodError: super: no superclass method `latitude' for #<MappableTable id: nil>

Comment: You can't call an overridden method after you've included the module. If you need to override the module's behavior for specific methods, redefine the methods on the class after you have included the module.

Comment: Yeah, I know I can do this logic on the Model. Was hoping not to have to do it in each Model including the Module. Thanks.

Comment: Hang on, I think I overlooked the fact that these are ActiveRecord models. Are you trying to provide a default value when a particular attribute is missing?

Comment: Yes. And hoping to do it in the concern.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the `defined?` method provided by ruby

```
def longitude
  if defined?(super)
    super || centroid.x
  else
    centroid.x
  end
end

def latitude
  if defined?(super)
    super || centroid.y
  else
    centroid.y
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could override the method and rely on the ActiveRecord model's `attributes` hash (where the values are stored):

```
module Mappable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def longitude
    attributes[:longitude] || centroid.x
  end

  # etc...
end
```

I haven't used this technique myself, so there might be some gotchas I haven't thought of. Write some tests and give it a try.